# What is a "schema provider" in an RDBMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Could someone please define what is meant by a schema provider? I'm familiar with DB schema (in this context, I take them to mean a named, logical container for DB objects). Why would a schema provider be useful? From a high level, how do they operate?

The context here is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Two suggestions --

1. Identify the context for your question.  
2. Google for "schema provider".

Comment: I did search online before posting. Could you please reply with a link to one of the pages you found that answers my questions? I'm not finding one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A schema provider is something external to RDBMS. Schema provider is API or class that gives you ability to retrieve DB schema from your code. [SqlConnection.GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema(VS.90).aspx) can be considered as schema provider for SQL Server. Schema provider is the code that you need if you want to navigate db schema in your app.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833285.aspx

> A database schema provider implements all the services that are specific to a particular brand and version of a database (such as SQL Server 2008). This includes the parser that reads and writes the scripts for that database; the *Script Domain Object Model* (Script DOM) that represents the scripts; and the *Schema Model* that models the objects, relationships, and properties of the database objects.

I have not used a schema provider, but it seems to be a service that can provide metadata about your database.  It's separate from the database itself.

I infer from the discussion that a different schema provider must be implemented for each brand of database (MS SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.).  A schema provider can provide generic, database-independent metadata through a common API, and also a schema provider for a given brand can be extended to provide database-specific metadata.  Sort of like ODBC for metadata.

Another way of looking at a schema provider is like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but implemented as a service, with an API.